# Is this question acceptable for this site?

Tags: discussion

> Is there any way to send a popup message from a Linux systen to a "random" laptop/tablet/mobile linked to my Wireless network ? For example, if I let my WLAN open and I see a not recognized computer connected to it, is there anyway to send to that device a message ?
>
> On the other hand, if I am connected to someone else open network and they may or may not be aware that their network is open, can I send them a message warning that I am accessing their network?

Is this question acceptable for this site?

PS: I have no practical application for this is just curiosity.

Comment: Note that questions that have already been posted will naturally be migrated to sites they're on topic for. There is no reason to post any question twice on the Stack Exchange network, [no matter what users who can't even get our domain right seem to tell you](http://superuser.com/questions/406616/how-to-send-a-popup-message-to-unknown-computer-connected-to-my-wlan#comment462970_406616).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I would consider that as a valid question. You have a computer problem `need to inform other users on the network` looking for a solution on how to do that.

And well, I felt like answering:

> You can only do this if the computer provides a service to do this, which is often enabled by default.
>
> You could hook up into their network traffic, but that would be considered illegal; just accessing their network is actually already illegal as well. *Unless you live somewhere where it is not, YMMV...*

But perhaps there are interesting approaches to this that might work.

Comment: Hi Tom thanks a lot for the information. So it seems that this is a reasonable question for the main site.

Comment: @Leandro: Yes, there is no problem just trying. I don't see how it does not adhere to the [Super User FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) and it really feels welcome...

Comment: You forgot the part where he's already asked on another site and should just wait for migration.

Comment: @DanielBeck: The Stack Exchange team forgot a way to check for cross-site duplicates, I wouldn't be surprised if this question also made its way to http://security.stackexchange.com...